# Inner and outer margins and paddings in a mdframed box

Tags: mdframed, double-sided

I am trying to get a background on theorems and such extending onto the *outer* margin of a two-sided document, using the interface provided by `thmtools.sty` to `mdframed`.

There is a catch, though: `mdframed` deals with inner and outer margins of a two-sided document using the options `innermargin` and `outermargin`, and that works nicely… but to get what would be the padding in CSS I was using the options `innerleftmargin` and `innerrightmargin` right before I turned my document into a two-sided one, and there is no `innerinnermargin`/`inneroutermargin` options to do this two-sidedly.

For example, consider:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\mdfdefinestyle{style}{%
  hidealllines=true,
  backgroundcolor={red!50},
  innermargin=-0pc,
  outermargin=-6pc,
  innerleftmargin=0pc,
  innerrightmargin=6pc
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=style]
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}

\newpage

\begin{mdframed}[style=style]
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}

\newpage

\begin{mdframed}[style=style]
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

I don't think `mdframed` has this built in.

> Can anyone provide a quick hack to do this?

Comment: Why don't you use tcolorbox?

Comment: @Ulrike, How does one do this with tcolorbox?

Comment: By looking in the documentation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, before asking you that I spent an hour playing with oversize/enlarge left by/grow to left by/toggle left and right/toggle enlargments/left/right and a few of the other hundreds of options tcolorbox has and was not able to get a box overspilling to both margins larger on the outer one in which text is set as normal. But thank you. That was very helpful. I would have never thought of reading the docs.

Answer (score 2):

With tcolorbox you can do it like this:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[grow to right by=2cm,if odd page={right=2cm}{left=2cm},toggle enlargement]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\newpage

\begin{tcolorbox}[grow to right by=2cm,if odd page={right=2cm}{left=2cm},toggle enlargement]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\newpage

\begin{tcolorbox}[grow to right by=2cm,if odd page={right=2cm}{left=2cm},toggle enlargement]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, thanks. If a box is breakable and actually gets broken across a pagebreak, then the second half gets the same margins as the first half — which are the wrong ones. I guess this is something that should be fixed in tcolorbox?

Comment: You can see this by changing the `[1]` in the first `\lipsum` to `[1-10]`, adding the `breakable` option to the `\usepackage{tcolorbox}`, and the `breakable` option to the `tcolorbox`es.

Comment: It can be done with breakable boxes too but better ask a new question so that others can answer it too. I have no time now.